# SSL Error while publishing extract to tableau server

Tags: java, tableau-api

Getting the following error while publishing an extract into Tableau server.

```
com.tableausoftware.TableauException: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
    at com.tableausoftware.server.ServerConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.tableau.sample.PublishOrder.main(PublishOrder.java:31)
CURL_ERROR - Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
com.tableausoftware.TableauException: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
    at com.tableausoftware.server.ServerConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.tableau.sample.PublishOrder.main(PublishOrder.java:31)
```

I am using online Tableau server and its version is 10.0

Here is my java code. This is same as the sample provided in [Tableau documentation](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_samples_java.htm%3FTocPath%3DTableau%2520SDK%2520Samples%7C_____2)

```
import com.tableausoftware.TableauException;
import com.tableausoftware.common.*;
import com.tableausoftware.server.*;

public class PublishOrder {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        try {
            // Initialize Tableau Server API
            ServerAPI.initialize();

            // Create the server connection object
            ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection();

            // Connect to the server
            serverConnection.connect("https://xxx.online.tableau.com", "xxx@example.com", "xxx", "xxx");

            // Publish order-java.tde to the server under the default project with name Order-java
            serverConnection.publishExtract("order-java.tde", "default", "Order-java-ubuntu", false);

            // Disconnect from the server
            serverConnection.disconnect();

            // Destroy the server connection object
            serverConnection.close();

            // Clean up Tableau Server API
            ServerAPI.cleanup();
        }
        catch (TableauException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am running this java code from ubuntu 12.04.
Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Samuel , looks like a bug in the API. https://community.tableau.com/message/470813#470813

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the CA certificates are not available on your system. Check if the file `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` exists. You may also need to update these certificates using [update-ca-certificates](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html).

Comment: ```/usr/local/share/ca-certificates``` does not contain any file. Do I need to copy files from ```/usr/share/ca-certificates/``` to ```/usr/local/share/ca-certificates```?

Comment: Copying the files to ```/usr/local/share/ca-certificates``` does not solve this issue. Also ```sudo update-ca-certificates``` didn't help